# Insert row with total under each group

Tags: vba, excel

I need to insert a row with a total and a page break under each group.

I tried the following to insert the row, however it inserted more than one row, when I want just one.

```
Sub macro()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastrow1 As Long

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")     
lastrow1 = sh1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow1

   If sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = "sell" Then
      sh1.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Insert
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on VBA but it sure looks like your code will insert a row every time it finds "sell" hence multiple rows inserted.

Try adding a break after you insert the row to get you out of the for loop.

hope this helps.
AH Note, in VBA `Exit For` is used to break out of for loops
 so your code would be

```
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")     
lastrow1 = sh1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
    If sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = "sell" Then
       sh1.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Insert
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with more than two different strings in column A

```
Sub InsertTotals()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lLastRow = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lLastRow + 1 To 2 Step -1
        If sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> sh1.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            sh1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using Excel's built-in subtotals.  It's not for inserting rows per se, but if your ultimate goal is to subtotal column B, this may be more suitable.

```
Sub InsertSubtotals()

    Dim rTransactions As Range
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sh1.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
    sh1.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Type", "Amount")

    Set rTransactions = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    rTransactions.Resize(, 2).Subtotal 1, xlSum, Array(2)

End Sub
```